# ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '"6029"' for column 'Industry_Code' at row 1 not sure why this is?

Tags: mysql, file, csv

Im trying to input a csv file contating serveral thousand lines into mysql database but keep getting this error and the data type i defined for "industry_code" is bigint but I undertand some of my fields for that  column in the cvs file are empty but it isnt complaining about them, it complaining about the 6029 number.

I will post below ppictures of my command line loading code, my databse structure and my csv file.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Lines of data in my csv file:**

```
5   CARIBBEAN DEVELOPMENT BANK  PO BOX 408  ST MICHEALS SM  WI  Barbados    Caribbean Development Bank  6029    Banking Caribbean Development Bank  6029    Banking

6   GOVERNMENT OF ARUBA SERRICIO DI COMPUTER CENTRAL    ORANJESTAD  OR  NA  ARUBA   Government of Aruba 9199    Government  Government of Aruba 9199    Government

7   LIFE OF JAMAICA INSURANCE CO LTD    28 BARBADOS AVE KINGSTON 5  KNG 0   JAMAICA Sagicor Life Jamaica Limited    6311    Insurance   Sagicor Life Jamaica Limited    6311    Insurance

8   BANCO POPULAR DOMINICANO    AVE J F KENNEDY 20  SANTO DOMINGO   SD  0   DOMINICAN REPUBLIC  Banco Popular Dominicano C. por A.-Banco Multiple   6021    Banking Grupo Popular S A   6712    Other Financial Services

9   BANCO MULTIPLE LEON SA  AVE J F KENNEDY 135 SANTO DOMINGO   SD  0   DOMINICAN REPUBLIC  Banco Multiple Leon, S.A.   6021    Banking Banco Multiple Leon, S.A.   6021    Banking

10  BARBADOS TELEPHONE CO LTD   WINDSOR LODGE GOVERNMENT HILL   ST MICHAELS SM  0   Barbados    

11  BARBADOS NATIONAL BANK  JAMES ST    BRIDGETOWN  BR  0   Barbados    Barbados Tyre Centre Limited    5013    Wholesale   Art Holding Inc.    6719    Other Financial Services

12  CHASE MANHATTAN BANK NA 28 TONG CHONG ST    HONG KONG   HK  0   HONG KONG (Special Administrative Region of China)  Chase Manhattan Trust Co (HK) Ltd 6733  Other Financial Services    Chase Manhattan Trust Co (HK) Ltd   6733    Other Financial Services

13  CITICORP    89 JALAN AMPANG KUALA LUMPUR    KUL 50754   MALAYSIA    CITICORP NOMINEE (M) SDN BHD    8742    Professional Services   Citigroup Inc.  6021    Banking

2294    DEPT OF NATIONAL DEFENSE    9 GROVE ST  DARTMOUTH   NS  B3A 3C5 CANADA  Government of Canada    9711    Government  Government of Canada    9121    Government
```

**Lines of data in my csv file viewd in text editor:**

```
5,"CARIBBEAN DEVELOPMENT BANK","PO BOX 408","ST MICHEALS","SM","WI","Barbados","Caribbean Development Bank","6029","Banking","Caribbean Development Bank","6029","Banking"

6,"GOVERNMENT OF ARUBA","SERRICIO DI COMPUTER CENTRAL","ORANJESTAD","OR","NA","ARUBA","Government of Aruba","9199","Government","Government of Aruba","9199","Government"

7,"LIFE OF JAMAICA INSURANCE CO LTD","28 BARBADOS AVE","KINGSTON 5","KNG","0","JAMAICA","Sagicor Life Jamaica Limited","6311","Insurance","Sagicor Life Jamaica Limited","6311","Insurance"

8,"BANCO POPULAR DOMINICANO","AVE J F KENNEDY 20","SANTO DOMINGO","SD","0","DOMINICAN REPUBLIC","Banco Popular Dominicano C. por A.-Banco Multiple","6021","Banking","Grupo Popular S A","6712","Other Financial Services"

9,"BANCO MULTIPLE LEON SA","AVE J F KENNEDY 135","SANTO DOMINGO","SD","0","DOMINICAN REPUBLIC","Banco Multiple Leon, S.A.","6021","Banking","Banco Multiple Leon, S.A.","6021","Banking"

10,"BARBADOS TELEPHONE CO LTD","WINDSOR LODGE GOVERNMENT HILL","ST MICHAELS","SM","0","Barbados","","","","","",""

11,"BARBADOS NATIONAL BANK","JAMES ST","BRIDGETOWN","BR","0","Barbados","Barbados Tyre Centre Limited","5013","Wholesale","Art Holding Inc.","6719","Other Financial Services"

12,"CHASE MANHATTAN BANK NA","28 TONG CHONG ST","HONG KONG","HK","0","HONG KONG (Special Administrative Region of China)","Chase Manhattan Trust Co (HK) Ltd","6733","Other Financial Services","Chase Manhattan Trust Co (HK) Ltd","6733","Other Financial Services"

13,"CITICORP","89 JALAN AMPANG","KUALA LUMPUR","KUL","50754","MALAYSIA","CITICORP NOMINEE (M) SDN BHD","8742","Professional Services","Citigroup Inc.","6021","Banking"

2294,"DEPT OF NATIONAL DEFENSE","9 GROVE ST","DARTMOUTH","NS","B3A 3C5","CANADA","Government of Canada","9711","Government","Government of Canada","9121","Government"
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check out the number in plain text editor, where you can see it in its raw format. There may be speechmarks around the values.

Comment: @Shadow yes! there is speech marks around every field when I open it in a text editor. Is there a way to remove them all or a statment to put into sql to forget them kind of thing? As dont want to manually remove 200k speech marks. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not useful publishing an image of a csv file. You are more likely to get help if you add sample data as text to the question same applies to the rest of the unusable images published here.

Comment: @P.Salmon ok i will do that now

Comment: Fix the data in the export. No point to complicate yourlife afterwards

Comment: @Shadow I didnt export it hence the issue. I was given this file as past of a task if that makes sense?

Comment: In your CSV data, all data columns are treating as a string, enclosed with "". In MySQL, this column is defined as an integer. MYSQL won't accept incorrect data type/format. The solution is to open this in the text editor and removes "" and try to export again.

Comment: is every other row really empty in the csv file?

Comment: Then import the file into excel, let excel do the conversion for you, then export it again as a csv.

Comment: @Shadow but when you open it in excel the speach marks dont show?

Comment: Excel will remove those if the field is converted into a numeric.